# matching similar text in sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server, pattern-matching

I have username which is manually entered by diffrent end users. There is no validation mechanism while inputting username hence there could be spelling error . For example user can 
enter Tina,Teena for same username . I need to return Tina when i Input Tina or vice versa.

Elaborately

```
SELECT * FROM tbl where where username='tina'
```

should return Tina, Teena and so on

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could investigate the `SOUNDEX` function in T-SQL. It would match Teena to Tina for instance (and visa-versa).

See http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187384.aspx

As the function name suggests, it matches words that sound the same. So, although it would match Tina to Teena, it wouldn't match Tina to Sina (as they don't 'sound' the same).

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT name 
FROM   (SELECT 'tina' AS name 
        UNION ALL 
        SELECT 'teena' AS name 
        UNION ALL 
        SELECT 'tena' AS name)tmp 
WHERE  Soundex(name) LIKE '%' + Soundex('tina') + '%'
```

Answer (score 1):

You can refer either soundex or diffrence

```
Select Soundex('Teena'),Soundex('Tina')
```

soundex returns `T500` for both so both are similar words

```
Select Difference('Teena','Tina')
```

returns 4, more the difference more is similarity